# J2ME Java - How to take part of an image and scale it up

Tags: java, graphics, java-me, image-manipulation

So this is what I want to do:

I have an image from which I want to take just a part of it. Let's say the image is 50px by 50px, I want to take the top left corner only 10px by 10px. so x=0, y=0, w=10, h=10

Then I want to paint this top corner, but in size 100px by 100px.

Does anyone know if this is possible? If so how would I go about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First take a look at [getClip](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Graphics.html#clip). This will allow you to draw a part of your image.
Regarding scaling - you will have to write / find a procedure that does that as I know J2ME MIDP doesn't have any methods that offer this.
Google search finds this (untested by me)
http://willperone.net/Code/codescaling.php